# Como salvar um trabalho em python pra não precisar rodar tudo cada vez que abre o script?

Tags: python

Estou trabalhando em um projeto de análise de dados no jupyter, trabalho com cerca de 5 data frames diferentes (quais são importados de CSVs) e relacionados através de uma chave ou outra, a partir desses DFs e suas relações, dentro do jupyter, começo a verificar a consistência dos dados, fazer análises, criar novos datas frames e assim por diante.

Meu problema é: cada vez que fecho o jupyter e vou retomar o trabalho, só fica salvo os outputs e os scripts de cada notebook, mas para obter os objetos gerados eu preciso sempre rodar tudo de novo desde o início.

Pesquisei um pouco e vi alguns meios de serialização pra ir salvando um a um, objeto por objeto (num ***pickle***, ***feather*** ou algum outro meio), e depois importa-los também um a um, mas isso me parece extramente trabalhoso, tanto quanto rodar tudo de novo...

Gostaria de saber se há alguma outra forma de salvar o trabalho, algo como uma imagem, tipo o ***.rdata*** para R, pra quando abrir o jupyter, ter um fácil acesso ao que vinha sendo desenvolvido.

Qualquer informação, ou compartilhamento de como vocês salvam seus trabalhos já vai me ajudar muito. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim - o caminho é de fato usar uma serialização como Pickle, mas não é tão trabalhoso assim -
(na verdade,  Jupyter tem um atalho para executar todas as células em sequência - você está usando isso? Não deveria dar trabalho)

O fato é que a forma de trabalhar com o Jupyter é mio que um itnermediário entre programação tradicional e uma planilha - ao fazer análize de dados, muitas das células você vai usar como rascunho, mudar parâmetros e expressões, não vai quere rrodar de novo - e vai ter outras células como base, onde você está lendo suas fontes de dado, montando os dataframes, etc... que provavelmente são o que você quer executar toda vez. Então dá pra entender por que simplesmente "executar todas as células" pode não ser prático - já que as células usadas para rascunho e experimentação serão processadas também.

Uma saída, antes de partir para precisar serializar as coisas, é colocar elementos mais próximos de "programação", com o uso de funções.

As células do Notebook, podendo ser re-executadas a qualquer momento fazem alguns dos papeis que temos em funções - e aí tendemos a deixar todo o código "solto" nas células - e isso leva a essa necessidade de re-executar tudo.

No entanto, se você colocar todo o código para criar os dataframes que você precisa em funções, e amarrar tudo numa função única de inicialização, vai precisar executar só essa função - sem ficar selecionando células para executar, etc...

Então, de forma mais concreta, vamos dizer que você tenha

cel 1:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
# outros impots

df1 = pd.read_csv(...)
# outros passos para estruturar o df1
```

cel 2:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(...)
# passos para estruturar o df2
```

E assim por diante - 
Você pode colocar as chamadas dessas células em funções - ficando com algo como:

cel1

```
# isole todas as importações numa única celula
```

cel2

```
def cria_df1():
    global df1
    df1 = pd.read_csv(...)
    # demais passos
```

...
cel n:

```
def inicializa():
     cria_df1()
     cria_df2()
     cria_df3()
     cria_df4()
     cria_df5()
```

Pronto, agora ao começar o trabalho, só é necessário executar as importações,
e, na própria célula em que você vai começar a trabalhar executar

`inicializa()`  -  (a chamada também pode estar na mesma célula em que a função 
`inicializa` está definida, claro - aí você executa só aquela célula)

---

Agora, se o problema não for só a quantidade de passos e ter que executar todos clicando nas células, mas sim, que haja tanto processamento envolvido que a inicialiação demora mais que alguns segundos, pode valer a pena serializar os dataframes e carregar de volta os dados já processados.

Para isso, o módulo pickle do Python é o suficiente. Sugiro estruturar o salvamento e o carregamento dos serializados em funções, pelos mesmos motivos acima.

cel m:

```
def salva_tudo():
    import pickle
    pickle.dump((df1, df2, df3, df4, df5),  open("dados_mastigados.pickle", "wb"), protocol=-1)

def carrega_tudo():
    global df1, df2, df3, df4, df5
    import pickle
    df1, df2, df3, df4, df5 = pickle.load(open("dados_mastigados.pickle", "rb"))
```

Pronto - basta você chamar  a função `carrega_tudo()` para os dados dos datframes serem restaurados em memória no ponto em que estavam quando `salva_tudo()`  foi chamada em uma sessão anterior.

---

Modularizar parte do código com funções é fundamental - mas além disso, o próprio Jupyter notebbok tem várias funcionalidades, independentes do Python, que permitem melhorar o fluxo de trabalho também - incluindo executar programas em Python inteiros que estão em arquivos, marcar células para não serem executadas quando se manda "executar tudo", etc ---

Este artigo cobre bastante dessas funcionalidades:

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-effortlessly-optimize-jupyter-notebooks-e864162a06ee

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou muito! De fato sou novo em python, e apesar de estar no início das análises e os processos não estarem demorando tanto pra rodar denovo, estava preocupando quando de fato fosse haver muitas transformações e procedimentos que demorassem mais no processamento.

Sinto muito isso que disse do código desorganizado, já que muitas células realmente são usadas somente para teste/rascunho, você tem alguma sugestão para organiza-los melhor? Ou recomendaria algum outro software?

Comment: Para o tipo de exploração de dados que tem que se fazer com dataframes, o notebook é  a melhor coisa mesmo.

O melhor é ganhar familiaridade com funções, como mencionei na resposta - mas há várias outras funcionalidades do Jupyter em si, inclusive macros, e diretivas para não executar algumas células automaticamente quando executar tudo - vou colocar o link para um bom artigo sobre isso na resposta.